# Is this a correct way of using structural induction to prove type uniqueness?

Tags: proof-techniques, type-theory, induction

I was reading the book "Types and Programming Languages" by Benjamin C. Pierce, paying attention to proofs so I could learn proof techniques.
In the parts discussing the simply typed $\lambda$-calculus, I came across a theorem called "Uniqueness of Types", and its proof details are not given, so I tried to write down details of the proof, but not very sure I am doing it correctly.

By searching the internet, I find out that we should do existence and uniqueness to prove uniqueness. I think the focus is on uniqueness by assuming there are two types and proving they are the same.
The details of terms, types, and proof are given below.

terms $t ::= x \, \mid \lambda x:T.t \, \mid t_1 \, t_2 \, \mid \, true \, \mid \, false \, \mid \, {\bf if} \, t \, {\bf then} \, t \, {\bf else} \, t $

types $T ::= bool \, \mid \, T \rightarrow T$

Inversion Lemma as follows

1. if $\Gamma \vdash  true : R$, then $R = bool$.
2. if $\Gamma \vdash  false : R$, then $R = bool$.
3. if $\Gamma \vdash {\bf if} \, t_1 \, {\bf then} \, t_2 \,{\bf else} \,t_3:R $,   then $\Gamma \vdash t_1:bool$ and $\Gamma \vdash t_2,t_3 :R$.
4. if $\Gamma \vdash x :R$,  then $x:R \in \Gamma$.
5. if $\Gamma \vdash  \lambda x:T_1.t_1:R$, then $R=T_1 \rightarrow R_1$ for some $R_1$ with $\Gamma, x:T_1 \vdash t_1:R_1$.
6. if $\Gamma \vdash t_1 t_2 :R$ , then there is some type $T_1$ such that $\Gamma \vdash t_1 : T_1 \rightarrow R$ and $\Gamma \vdash t_2 : T_1$

I did not list typing rules, since we can see them from inversion lemma. here is proof below.

**[Uniqueness of Types]**
In a given context $\Gamma$, a term $t$ has one unique type.

**proof**: The proof is by structural induction on $t$.

The cases of $t$ are either $true$ or $false$ is obvious by the inversion Lemma.

When $t$ is a variable, it has a unique type by the inversion Lemma and by the fact of distinctness of variables in $\Gamma$.

When $t$ is ${\text if}$ $t_1$ then $t_2$ else $t_3$, assume it has two types $T_1$ and $T_2$.
By the inversion Lemma, we have $t_1 : bool$, $t_2$ has types $T_1$ and $T_2$, and  $t_3$ has types $T_1$ and $T_2$ as well.
By induction hypothesis, assume that $t_2$ and $t_3$ have unique types, which means $T_1$ is the same as $T_2$, which gives that $t$ has a unique type.

When $t$ is $\lambda x:T_1.t_1$, let's assume $t$ has types $T_1 \rightarrow T_2$ and $T_3 \rightarrow T_4$.
By the inversion Lemma, it must be $T_1=T_3$, and $t_1$ has types $T_2$ and $T_4$.
Using induction hypothesis assumes $t_1$ has a unique type, which means $T_2 =T_4$, so $t$ has a unique type.

That is it. could anyone point out errors and mistakes, so I can learn from mistakes.
(There is no one around me to discuss together, so I am posting it here to get help)
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Looks like a pretty good proof!
You could shorten the case of lambda, the type of $t$ can be $T_1 \to T_2$ or $T_1 \to T_3$ as the argument type $x : T_1$ is given.
For completeness, the missing case is that of $t_1 t_2$ which also follows straight from induction.

Comment: Also your theorem should probably say "$t$ has *at most* one type".

Comment: @Apoorv thank you very much for your confirmation. I will fix the lambda case, and add application case.

Comment: @cody very nice point, thank you!